# Zend Framework 1.12 and ajax returning error 500

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I have a simple ajax request in my view page that i want to bind to an action in my controller :

```
function updateDates(id,val){

$.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "<?=APPLICATION_URL_ADMIN?>campaign/changedate", 
            data: ({id:id,duree:val}),                              
            cache: false,
            error: function(msg){
                alert('Il y a eu une erreur.');
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log('ok');
              window.location.href=window.location.href;
            }
      });


}
```

and in my controller :

```
public function changedateAction()
{

    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('changedate', 'html')->initContext(); 

    global $mySession;
    $db = new Db();

    $data = $this->_request->getPost(); 


    $data_update['campaign_length'] = $data['duree'];
    $data_update['launch_date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $condition = "campaign_id='" . $data['id'] . "' ";
    $db->modify(LAUNCHCAMPAIGN, $data_update, $condition);

}
```

Here's the request string rendered in the chrome console, which is fine :
    http://www.mydomain.ndd/admin/campaign/changedate?id=4&duree=45

It's throwing an error 500 and i don't know why. Can anyone help me ?

Edit:

I changed my action in the controller, but my db is still not updated

```
public function changedateAction()
{       

    global $mySession;
    $db = new Db();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        // makes disable renderer
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        //makes disable layout
        $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){ 

            $data = $this->_request->getPost();                 

            $data_update['campaign_length'] = $data['duree'];
            $data_update['launch_date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $condition = "campaign_id='" . $data['id'] . "' ";
            $db->modify(LAUNCHCAMPAIGN, $data_update, $condition);


            $this->view->text =  $data['duree'];.' processed';
        }
     }

}
```

Can somebody help me ? i'am stuck.

Thanks

Comment: http code 500 is an indicator that something went wrong on the server. it could be a configuration error in the webserver setting, but usually it is an error in the php code (ZF returns 500 error if it encounters a recoverable error/exception). Inspect the response of your ajax call to see additional informations regarding the error. check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php to learn about ways to get more meaningful error messages

Answer (score 1):

Your controller populates `$data` from **POST** via:

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost();
```

but your request passes the `id` and `duree` values via **GET** in the query-string:

```
http://www.mydomain.ndd/admin/campaign/changedate?id=4&duree=45
```

The result is that `$data['id']` and `$data['duree']` are not defined when you attempt to use them to build `$data_update`.

A var_dump/die of the `$data` should confirm that those keys are unset.

Instead, try pulling the querystring data using:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$id = $request->getParam('id');
$duree = $request()->getParam('duree');
```

Not tested, just a thought...

**UPDATE**

There is some inconsistency of request method in your description. Of course, the AJAX request you describe is POST and you seem to be passing the `id` and `duree` keys properly. My answer focused on your reference to the url:

http://www.mydomain.ndd/admin/campaign/changedate?id=4&duree=45

which clearly passes the data via GET.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic on the Controller side looks fine.

Assuming the controller you trying to read is called "campaign" , Try the following:

```
function updateDates(id,val){

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // DUE TO THE NATURE OF HOW ZEND WORKS YOU NEED ONLY NEED TO PROVIDE /CONTROLLER/ACTION
        url: "/campaign/changedate",

         // I USE THIS DATA TYPE WHEN SENDING AJAX REQUESTS IN ZEND
          dataType:  'json',

        // YOU DO NOT NEED THE () ONLY {}
        data: { 
            id:id,
            duree:val
        },
        cache: false,
        error: function(msg){ 
            alert('Il y a eu une erreur.');
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log('ok'); 

            // IF YOU TRYING TO RELOAD THE CURRENT PAGE USE THIS
            location.reload();
        } 
    });
}
```

add this at the end of your action so that it returns back to your ajax request;

```
echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode(array(
                        'success' => true
                ));
exit;
```

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your reply.

I think there's something wrong in my controller

How do you parse the json data received in the controller ?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneJoo. please see additions to my answer to put inside your controller.

Comment: is  '$data = $this->_request->getPost(); ' the right method to get the values ?